# How to Get VDO File from Server

Tags: iphone

I want to load a file from a server (e.g. http://www.myname.com/myfile.mov) with my app and play it with `VDO MPMoviePLayer`. However it uses `NSURLconnect` to connect to the URL.

How can I convert data of the type `NSdata` to `NSURL` for use in `VDO`?

Answer (score 1):

don't use NSURLConnection to download the data yourself, just pass the URL to the movie player.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myname.com/myfile.mov"];
MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
```